# How to break a audit and history table to find the nth event after nth event in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, partition

I have a audit table in SQL that simply contains some narrative, the datestamp and a linkid that links narratives to a particular object. When reading this table I would search by object id and then order the narratives by date to understand what is happeneing.

Obviously this approach does not work programmatically so I wanted to know how I could build logic to identify specific events.

For example a single object may have multiple narratives that say 'Received new host ...'. And it may have multiple narratives that say 'Matched against object xxx...'.

I would like to partition (?) this table in a way that I can see what the 1st 'Matched against ...' time after the nth 'Receive new ...' record was.

Is this possible?

- The fields in the table are

**TradeRef** - unique PK and irrelevant 
**TradeId** - the grouped trade ID which is what I will be using 
**AuditDate** 
**AuditNarrative**

- Sample Data

The following is an example of the data for one particular trade Id. I have shown the date and the narrative so you can work out what is happening. To link this back to my question - I want to find out the 1st match that happened after the 2nd 'Received new host contract' but ignore where the end of the narrative is PHONE_CONFIRMED. So simply reading through the records the record I want is the 'Matched event...' record on 29/09/15 15:09:23. Please note that this is a simple example and there are other trades with many more match events and new host contracts coming in!

13/07/15 14:49:00 Received new host contract   
13/07/15 15:22:39 Moved to Priority 'Host Unmatched' Queue   
13/07/15 19:17:44 Received new counterparty contract   
13/07/15 19:21:04 Automated perfect match  C123 
13/07/15 19:21:04 Automated perfect match  H123 
13/07/15 19:21:05 Match Event generated for Host Trade H123 and Counterparty Trade C123  C123 
12/08/15 15:36:18 Automated unmatch request   
12/08/15 15:36:18 Unmatched Event generated for Host trade: H123 and Counterparty Trade: C123   
12/08/15 15:36:18 Automated unmatch request   
12/08/15 15:36:18 Processed Cancellation   
12/08/15 15:42:25 Moved to Priority 'Host Unmatched' Queue   
12/08/15 16:00:44 Cpty cancelled their trade stoday. Emailed James Newman to advise   
12/08/15 16:23:23 Received cancelled host contract   
12/08/15 16:23:23 Processed Cancellation   
12/08/15 16:24:04 Received new host contract   
12/08/15 16:57:24 Moved to Priority 'Host Unmatched' Queue   
17/08/15 21:57:58 Matched Event generated for Host Trade H123  PHONE_CONFIRMED 
17/08/15 21:57:58 Manual VCO   x 
17/08/15 21:57:58 previously mathced  Contact:x  Contact No:x  Contact Date:x Our Phone No:  x 
17/08/15 22:40:14 Manual unmatched   
17/08/15 22:40:14 Unmatched Event generated for Host trade: H123 and Counterparty Trade: PHONE_CONFIRMED   
17/08/15 22:42:21 Moved to Priority 'Host Unmatched' Queue   
10/09/15 22:01:53 Matched Event generated for Host Trade H123  PHONE_CONFIRMED 
10/09/15 22:01:53 Manual VCO   x 
10/09/15 22:01:53 Affirmations  affirmed via email  Contact:x  Contact No:x  Contact Date:x Our Phone No:  x 
29/09/15 15:09:23 Matched Event generated for Host Trade  H123  confirm received 
29/09/15 15:09:23 Manual counterparty sight paired  confirm received

Comment: I think you should include the table structure and some sample data showing us what you want.  Or, you can wait for Gordon Linoff to answer the question as is.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Apologies - details added now. Its MS SQL SERVER 2005

Answer (score 0):

The following query will partition the data for you based on the linked object ID.

```
SELECT  TradeId ,
        AuditNarrative ,
        AuditDate ,
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY TradeId, AuditNarrative ORDER BY AuditDate ASC ) Ranking
FROM    dbo.Audit
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. How does it tell me which is the 2nd Received new host and the 1st Matched Event after this?

Comment: Hmmmm ok this question got a lot more detail since I answered, hahaha. Well using the query above you would have a ranking of your items. You would be able to determine the date of the second reviewed host by just looking in the result of the select for a description of "new host" and a ranking of two. 

You would then run the same query again but this time look for records with a datetimestamp > than the time determined above. You would then look in the new dataset for a record with a description of "Matched event" with a ranking of 1.

Comment: Using the ranking does not work. The seconf received new host has a ranking of 15. Did you mean to partition by TradeId and AuditNarrative?

Comment: Hi sorry! yes you would need to partition by both those columns.

Comment: Yep thats perfect! Thanks

Comment: Awesome glad I could help :) Please upvote/mark as answer if you can